# How to call an webservice through curl with JSON Parameter?

Tags: web-services, curl

I have web service running on server `URL-http://localhost:8080/getdata`
I want to call the web service through curl which take an parameter {"time":"2016-3-30 13:47:13"}

can any one help me with syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"time\":\"2016-3-30 13:47:13\"}" http://localhost:8080/getdata

Comment: Worked like charm
One thing suppose I want to post the same data what ever I am getting from this curl command to another web service suppose http://localhost:9200 how to do it